# Oracle Trigger PLS-00103. Query with multiple rows in temporal variable

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger that raises error when someone attempts to rate a product which has not been bought. I have come up with a query to get the purchase history of a client :

```
SELECT nref 
FROM CartClient a 
INNER JOIN PaidCart b 
     ON a.idpurchase = b.idpurchase
INNER JOIN CartDetails c  
     ON b.idpurchase = c.idpurchase 
WHERE a.Id = '12345672X'
```

which works fine.

So the next trigger should check if the product of a new rating (:new.NRef) has not been bought, namely is not part of the result of the last query (NOT IN).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cant_rate
BEFORE INSERT ON Rating
FOR EACH ROW   
    BEGIN
        IF (:new.NRef NOT IN (SELECT nref FROM CartClient a 
                                   INNER JOIN PaidCart b 
                                      ON a.idpurchase = b.idpurchase
                                   INNER JOIN CartDetails c  
                                      ON b.idpurchase = c.idpurchase 
                                   WHERE a.Id =:new.Id)) THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20603,'Cant rate a not bought product');
        END IF;
    END;
```

I get error:

> "PLS-00103:Encountered the symbol “INNER” when expecting one of".

I have tried to store the result of the query in a temporal variable using SELECT INTO. But, it's a multiple row result. What could I do?

Comment: what is complete error message?

Comment: and if you are using 11g, 11G Forms does not support ANSI standard join syntax.

Comment: Forms? What makes you think it is about Forms, @eshirvana?

Comment: @Littlefoot just guessing, based on the error message

Comment: Hm, I'd rather base it on code I see - it says `create or replace trigger ...` which means that it is stored in the database; it is not a Forms trigger, so ... I'd say that your objection is wrong in this case, @eshirvana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about such an approach?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cant_rate
  BEFORE INSERT ON Rating
  FOR EACH ROW   
DECLARE
  l_exists NUMBER(1) := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(1)
    INTO l_exists
    FROM dual
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT nref FROM CartClient A 
                  INNER JOIN PaidCart b 
                     ON A.idpurchase = b.idpurchase
                  INNER JOIN CartDetails C  
                     ON b.idpurchase = C.idpurchase 
                  WHERE A.ID = :NEW.ID
                    AND a.nref = :NEW.nref           --> is it "a.nref"?
                 );
  IF l_exists = 0 THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20603,'Cant rate a not bought product');
  END IF;
END;
```

Note remark "is it a.nref?" - you never said which table owns that `nref` column so I presumed it is `cartclient`; modify it, if necessary.

---

As of your attempt: if you executed it in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, you'd see a message regarding subquery in `IF`; something like this:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
2/3       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/21      PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
```

So, no - you can't do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't get the actual error: PLS-00405 subquery not allowed in this context.

Simple stupid test:

```
BEGIN
   IF 1 NOT IN ( SELECT 2 FROM DUAL )
   THEN
      NULL;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

You can adjust your trigger in this way or similar:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cant_rate
BEFORE INSERT ON Rating
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_test   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

   SELECT CASE
            WHEN :new.NRef NOT IN ( SELECT nref
                                      FROM CartClient a 
                                      INNER JOIN PaidCart b 
                                         ON a.idpurchase = b.idpurchase
                                      INNER JOIN CartDetails c  
                                         ON b.idpurchase = c.idpurchase 
                                      WHERE a.Id = :new.Id
                                  )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
           END
    INTO l_test;
    FROM DUAL;

   IF l_test = 1
   THEN
    ...
    
   END IF;
END;
/
```